# Why do I get this undesired vertical space between "chapter #" and Chapter Heading?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, line-spacing

In my document, one of my chapter title lasts more than one line, so I want to increase the space between its lines. To do this, I used `\linespread{1.8}\selectfont` in the code below, but by using that, the space between "`Chapter #`" and the `Chapter Heading` increases, too. How can I avoid this latter undesired space? By the way, I'd prefer not to use additional packages like `titlesec` or `setspace`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries \linespread{2}\selectfont #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading which is very very very long}
Some text ...
‎\end{document}‎
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't! In your code you have a `vskip20\p@` and this remains constant. (See the below minimal, where I zeroed it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \fbox{\thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\Huge \bfseries \linespread{1.2}\selectfont #1\par\nobreak}}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Heading which is very very Hery long}
Some text ...
‎\end{document}‎
```

[image]

Also don't forget to modify the star version of the command using `\@make`**s**`chapterhead`

Comment: So I should use `\parbox` command to control the scope of `\linespread{1.2}\selectfont`, right?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan It is easier to adjust with a negative skip to suit e.g.`\vskip-30pt` on line 10.